# Why does Turkish Airlines want me to cancel my flight when I check-in?

Tags: check-in, turkish-airlines

I'm trying to check-in for flight TK1770 that's departing tomorrow and the check-in page is showing me the following error:

[image]

> An unexpected problem occurred in your flight numbered. Please review the flight details on your ticket.

When I click on "Cancel flight" it wants to give me a refund, but I want to check-in for the flight instead of cancelling it. Likewise Flightaware shows that TK1770 isn't actually cancelled and would depart on time tomorrow. What should I now do to complete the check-in?

**Update:** it was indeed a bug on the site. The flight itself went just fine.

Comment: Wrong title. TA does not want you to cancel your flight. It gives you the option to.

Comment: @JanDoggen I figured that much. The title is for better searchability.

Comment: @JanDoggen I wouldn't say the title is wrong. It reflects the OP's original understanding of the situation, and misunderstandings are typical starting points for questions.

Comment: Based on the UI given, you could easily make the case that to cancel the flight is strongly suggested. Whether they actually want you to, or it's a website error/oversight altogether is another issue.

Comment: Turkish Airlines is kind of the "good, but disastrous!" airline.

Comment: Better searchability would be to use the *error message* as part of the title.

Comment: @jpmc26 feel free to update it

Comment: Maybe I'm late but just go and enjoy your flight.
It's a website error

Comment: In risk of being labeled a "grammar-nazi"... @JanDoggen , if you use abbreviations for airline names, please use THY for Turkish Airlines.

Comment: @Fattie My experience is that it's a good airline with a disastrous website. :)

Comment: @fkraiem - you know, unfortunately they have horked my flights a couple of times, so I never fly with them anymore.  it's a shame coz they have some good qualities.  they very unfortunately do the thing (a lot) where if there's only a few people on a flight they cancel it for "technical" reasons.  of course, your mileage may vary  :O

Comment: it is a website issue app works fine
TRY TO CHECK IN THY APP ON YOUR PHONE It just worked fine for me

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I don't think they actually want you to cancel.  It's probably a website error.

Normally you'd expect "cancel flight" to be displayed as one option in addition to "check in", "change flight", etc, but I suspect for some reason those options are not being displayed.

You'll probably need to phone the airline to complete your check-in, or check in when you arrive at the airport.  If there actually is some problem with your reservation, the customer service staff can inform you in more detail what's going on.

Comment: Further evidence: `your flight numbered .` instead of `your flight numbered 123.`. It's rendering a template with null data.

Comment: I'd try another browser before calling having seen these issues before. Yes websites are supposed to be cross browser these days but so many aren't.

Comment: @MD-Tech And *in particular* airline websites are horrible in this respect.

Answer (score 18):

I already have flown with Turkish a couple of times; the site is not exactly a shining example how to write a (corporate) website.

Often to complete operations or even to authenticate, Safari does not work for me, or fails in strange ways and Firefox has to be used.

Frequently, some other operations are so much easier in their iOS application. For instance, it is so much easier to do check-ins in their iOS application than on their site.

Try another browser, or their mobile app, it might work for you.

PS. As trivia, I made check-in while in the Philippines in my iPhone, using their app, for our party of 4 persons, and also seated us all together.

It was relative fast and painless; it was also totally worth it, as we avoided the normal (long) queue at the airport, and went instead to the electronic check-in queue.

Using their site, I did not even managed to login, much less doing any check-in.

Comment: One of my pet peeves with Turkish is them just allowing a 24h-window for electronic check-in - the last 24h is always chaotic. In the past, some of other companies allowed a 48h window for international flights.

Comment: I wish airlines had automatic check in or at least an API so that you could automate it. But nope, you still have to click the buttons yourself every time :/

Comment: Given the quality of Turkish´s web site, having an API seems more on the science fiction realm.

Answer (score 7):

Try deactivating any ad blockers or similar extensions.

Comment: Any experience to back this up, or are you just guessing?

Comment: @JanDoggen this is really good advice most people, including myself, would not have thought of.  There is literally nothing else to be said besides "disable your ad blocker".

Comment: Deactivating ad blockers wont help with a site that has been badly designed/coded as theirs.  Speaking from experience.

Comment: Although disabling adblocker does help for some situations I don't think it's the case here. As someone else mentioned it's rendering an empty template (no flight number, no check in button as it's not bound to a flight), which probably means it's either a data issue (contact the airline) or a Javascript framework isn't loading (enable Javascript, or switch browser, or again contact airline).

Comment: CDNs are becoming increasingly common. A lot of critical website functionality often depends on loading a library such as `axios`, which may be done via CDN. If the ad blocker is blocking the CDN or a subdirectory, it causes the dependency to fail, which causes the site to not work (no axios = no data on my website, for example). While not a specific ad-blocker, my site is incompatible with Kaspersky's Internet Suite due to how they modify payment data form, for example, and the advice given here would address that.

Comment: It is not use talking about ad blockers, CDNs or whatever tecno-babble. Turkish's web site is simply very badly coded and does not work most of the time. They just need to develop a new site with another supplier.

Comment: Sorry about my short answer and I'm a little too late but Thebluefish explained exactly what I meant with my suggestion. I really don't know this website but probably it's just bad coding.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro et al. When trying to do something in websites that are showing errors or wrong behavior in general, addressing the situation in any way that does not start with disabling the AD blocker, and going ahead fighting the issue with the AD blocker still enabled, makes no sense. Absolute first step to take in such cases, even if such step wasn't the zero-time-consuming walk in the park that it is.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. I called the Turkish airlines Hotline and I got helped well.

The problem was that the arrival time was changed; before 09:30 am, now 09:20 am. But the system wasn't updated about this and so I couldn't manage my reservation. The call center agent updated it by himself and then it worked. Now I can manage my reservation again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my flight, I tried calling many numbers none helped, only the Turkish airline's number could confirm my flight +349 1 375 41 89, the girl informed me that my connected flight had a 5 minutes change. No big problems but I had to confirm. Now I can manage my reservation again!